# React useMemo hook 'retriggers' with undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useMemo hook in which the dependencies are undefined. The issue is this fires constantly.
Imagine in the below a, b and c were undefined.

```
  const something = useMemo(() => { 
    console.log('something changed');
    return 'test';
  }, [a, b, c]);
```

So I did a test with passing undefined directly:

```
  const something = useMemo(() => { 
    console.log('something changed');
    return 'test';
  }, [undefined]);
```

And this also logs many times.

From react docs [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) they say they compare values as so:

> React will compare each dependency with its previous value using the
> Object.is comparison.

But `Object.is(undefined, undefined) === true` so why does this re-trigger the useMemo?

Comment: I would guess that your component is unmounting and then remounting. Can you show more of the surrounding code, or a working example?

Comment: When you say "many times" do you mean 2 times on each page refresh? That's true for the strict mode of the React on initial render. Read more about it https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects

Comment: Here's an example where it's working correctly. It will do 2 copies of "something changed" due to strict mode (as taiwei tuan mentioned), but it doesn't repeat on every render. https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-herschel-3sxvd3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @NicholasTower I expected so too, so added a useEffect with no deps and that was only triggered once.

Comment: It seems to be triggering at least 3 times now, I'll try to reproduce

Comment: The answer seemed to be a hook re-rendering due to a variable passed as state that was being spread (therefore copied)